# SAM Timer counter / atmel ASF

Tags: c, embedded, atmel, c++, cortex-m4

I'm trying to implement function call after having timeroverflow or comparison of counter registers.

Chip: SAM4E

```
tc_init(TC0, 2, TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3);
tc_write_rc(TC0, 2, 750000);
tc_enable_interrupt(TC0,2,TC_IER_COVFS | TC_IER_CPCS);

NVIC_DisableIRQ(TC2_IRQn);
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TC2_IRQn);
NVIC_SetPriority(TC2_IRQn, 0);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TC2_IRQn);


tc_start(TC0,2);
```

I tried many codes that didn't work. I had to switch to TC0 so I could see the timer value actually changing:

> (TC0->TC_CHANNEL[2].TC_CV)

```
void TC2_Handler(void)
{
    ii++;
}
```

unfortunately this code doesn't work. (it has a bug that goes to infinite loop).

i can see timer value changing with this code but there is no interrupt handler working:

```
 sysclk_enable_peripheral_clock(ID_TC2);

tc_init(TC0, 2, TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3);
tc_write_rc(TC0, 2, 75000);
tc_enable_interrupt(TC0,2, TC_IER_COVFS  );

NVIC_DisableIRQ(TC2_IRQn);
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TC2_IRQn);
NVIC_SetPriority(TC2_IRQn, 0);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TC2_IRQn);


tc_start(TC0,2);
```

why is this not correct code?
why 'TC_IER_COVFS' doesn't trigger TC2_handler(). and it does not work also. (although i can see timer started)...
why 'TC_IER_CPCS' trigger fault ( i guess it goes to dummy_handler!).
what would be the correct way to fix this

Comment: Apart from that your question isn't Electrical Engineering related: Where in your software do you tell the build tool that "TC2_Handler" shall be your ISR?

Comment: @mic, i though its microcontrollers and embedded system is electronics related. electronics is electrical related. yeah i know that electrical is too wide but isnt electrical is where everybody post electrical / electronics?

Comment: @mic yes, its ASF code, 
__attribute__ ((section(".vectors")))
const DeviceVectors exception_table = {

 /* Configure Initial Stack Pointer, using linker-generated symbols */
 (void*) (&_estack),

 (void*) Reset_Handler,
 (void*) NMI_Handler,
 (void*) HardFault_Handler, .......  (void*) TC2_Handler,

Comment: @Hasanalattar, nope, if it's a primarily a programming problem, you'd go to Stackoverflow.com. However, this might be specific to hardware, so at least marginally on-topic. However, you've forgot to ask a specific question, so we've got nothing to answer!

Comment: @mic Firmware for microcontrollers ("bare-metal"/RTOS) is explicitly on-topic. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unfortunately this code doesn't work. (it has a bug that goes to infinite loop).

It is not an infinite loop: you do not clear the interrupt bit so when you return the interrupt is still pending and it goes back into the service routine.

I found some code I wrote a time ago for the SAM:

```
void TC0_Handler(void)
{ uint32_t dummy_sr;
  // must read status register to clear interrupt
  // This is unfortunately not (clearly?) mention in the datasheet
  dummy_sr = TC0->TC_CHANNEL[0].TC_SR;  

  // If we are running in one-shot mode disable the timer
  if (one_shot)
     TC0->TC_CHANNEL[0].TC_CCR = TC_CCR_CLKDIS;

  // Call the call back function
  (*t0_handler)();

}  // TC0_Handler
```

Comment: thanks, it seems like i've to set (TC_CMR_CPCTRG) when i run tc_init. i tried to find that i've to clear TC_SR still didnt find it yet althougth it works now i've to run more tests.

Comment: *"i tried to find that i've to clear TC_SR still didnt find it "* If I recall, I read the SR because most CPU's requires that and it started to work. Later I came across it somewhere . It explains my comment in the code :-)

Comment: hello, i want to put this as an answer, although 2 more points (why TC_IER_COVFS is not triggering the isr function) and why (tc1 and tc2 are not triggering also) .. not channels but the 3 timers/counters them self?

Comment: @Hasanalattar Just let it be. I am not doing this for the points.

Comment: the COVFS was triggering the ISR, however it takes 6hrs to reach to overflow value (12MHz XTAL -> SCLK PRES 2 -> TCCLK /32 ) = (2^32)/187500 / 3600sec = 6.36 Hours